# If Cell Starts with String from a List Return Number

Tags: excel, list, if-statement, macros

What I am looking for is either a formula or Macro/code that will allow me to do the following:

I have a list of the beginning of Postcodes, for example, "AB31, AB32, AB33, AB34", I need something that will return a value of 313 if the start of a cell contains a value from this list I have, and a value of 74 if it does not start with a value from that list.

Now the list is quite long, theres probably 100+ values in there. If there weren't so many values in the list I could use something like

> =IF(LEFT(K1,4)="AB51","313","72")

The Postcode will be in the K column, and the full list I need it to search through is

> AB31
>   AB32
>   AB33
>   AB34
>   AB35
>   AB36
>   AB37
>   AB38
>   AB40
>   AB41
>   AB42
>   AB43
>   AB44
>   AB45
>   AB46
>   AB47
>   AB48
>   AB49
>   AB50
>   AB51
>   AB52
>   AB53
>   AB54
>   AB55
>   AB56
>   BT
>   GY
>   HS
>   IM
>   IV1
>   IV2
>   IV3
>   IV4
>   IV5
>   IV6
>   IV7
>   IV8
>   IV9
>   IV10
>   IV11
>   IV12
>   IV13
>   IV14
>   IV15
>   IV16
>   IV17
>   IV18
>   IV19
>   IV20
>   IV21
>   IV22
>   IV23
>   IV24
>   IV25
>   IV26
>   IV27
>   IV28
>   IV30
>   IV31
>   IV32
>   IV36
>   IV40
>   IV41
>   IV42
>   IV43
>   IV44
>   IV45
>   IV46
>   IV47
>   IV48
>   IV49
>   IV51
>   IV52
>   IV53
>   IV54
>   IV55
>   IV56
>   IV63
>   J3
>   KA27
>   KA28
>   KW1
>   KW2
>   KW3
>   KW4
>   KW5
>   KW6
>   KW7
>   KW8
>   KW9
>   KW10
>   KW11
>   KW12
>   KW13
>   KW14
>   KW15
>   KW16
>   KW17
>   PA20
>   PA21
>   PA22
>   PA23
>   PA24
>   PA25
>   PA26
>   PA27
>   PA28
>   PA29
>   PA30
>   PA31
>   PA32
>   PA33
>   PA34
>   PA35
>   PA36
>   PA37
>   PA38
>   PA41
>   PA42
>   PA43
>   PA44
>   PA45
>   PA46
>   PA47
>   PA48
>   PA49
>   PA60
>   PA61
>   PA62
>   PA63
>   PA64
>   PA65
>   PA66
>   PA67
>   PA68
>   PA69
>   PA70
>   PA71
>   PA72
>   PA73
>   PA74
>   PA75
>   PA76
>   PA77
>   PA78
>   PH4
>   PH5
>   PH6
>   PH7
>   PH8
>   PH9
>   PH10
>   PH11
>   PH12
>   PH13
>   PH14
>   PH15
>   PH16
>   PH17
>   PH18
>   PH19
>   PH20
>   PH21
>   PH22
>   PH23
>   PH24
>   PH25
>   PH26
>   PH27
>   PH28
>   PH29
>   PH30
>   PH31
>   PH32
>   PH33
>   PH34
>   PH35
>   PH36
>   PH37
>   PH38
>   PH39
>   PH40
>   PH41
>   PH42
>   PH43
>   PH44
>   PH49
>   PH50
>   TR21
>   TR22
>   TR23
>   TR24
>   TR25
>   ZE

So if any Postcode in column K begins with any of those values, I would like the number 313 returning, if not the number 72 returning.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give example on how your sheets look like or else it is very difficult to answer.

what I will do

1. Put the list on a Column

[image: List]

2. Use combination of IF and Vlookup to loop through the list.

   ```
   =IF(VLOOKUP(LEFT(K1, 4),A:A,1,0)=LEFT(K1, 4),313,72)
   ```

   ```
   Column E    Column F Column G
   Post Code   Result   Formula
   AB31456     313      =IF(VLOOKUP(LEFT(E2,4),A:A,1,0)=LEFT(E2,4),313,72)
   KZ12398      72      =IF(VLOOKUP(LEFT(E2,4),A:A,1,0)=LEFT(E2,4),313,72)
   ```